# approach for generating cluster of xpaths from html files in perl

Tags: perl, xpath, cpan

As per one of project requirement, we have to come up with an approach and also suitable perl resource for fullfilling the following requirement.

Our requirement is that we get bulk of input data in html format and we have to write a parser to bring all the varities of input data into one generic formatted xml file.

now the challenge is that while writing parser we manually used to verify very few sample html files, that was failing for other sample html files, but is highly difficult to analyse all html files manually.

Due to the above we have come to a decision that we will have some analysis tool where all the variations in html structure can be monitored using xpaths.

Can you please any of you suggest which module is suitable for my work, I know `HTML::TreeBuilder::Xpath` will help me in giving xpaths, but any limitations in that module?

or else suggest me the best approach for understanding the analysis of the html file, most of us in our team are more familiar with perl, that's why prefer to go and write in perl.

Suggest me if any other technology can also be used more efficiently, or else within perl also what can be the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

If the html files are guaranteed to be well-formed xhtml, I'd take a look into xslt for transforming the input.

I'd check the output for missing data, since the structure of the input file is unknown. After transforming you can check for the missing data at known paths in the document.

a example how xslt works:

the html input file

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <body>
    <div class="foo">1</div>
    <div>
       <div class="bar">2</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

the stylesheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <!-- match the document root -->
    <data>
      <!-- apply all templates to the input document -->
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </data>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/html/body/div[@class='foo']">
    <!-- div with attribute class='foo' is expected only at /html/body/div -->
    <foo-out><xsl:value-of select="."></xsl:value-of></foo-out>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="//div[@class='bar']">
    <!--div with attribute class=bar can be anywhere  in the document-->
    <bar-out><xsl:value-of select="."></xsl:value-of></bar-out>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the output

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
  <foo-out>1</foo-out>
  <bar-out>2</bar-out>
</data>
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate answer to my question? because I have so many concerns regarding the approach and also the module which I decided to use?

Comment: xsl stands for EXtensible Stylesheet Language. you can use http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/XML-LibXSLT-1.94/LibXSLT.pm to transform the html-files. the advantage is that you don't have to write a parser youself. here is an example: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog

Comment: after the transformation you know the structure of your document since you defined it. xslt works like this:  you define several templates that transform the input data. every template transforms the imput data if it matches a path in the input document. this is done via xpath. the template transforms it acccording to your rules to the output document. if a path is not in the input document, nothing gets put in the output document.

After transformation you can exactly check what parts are there and what is missing